# Apache httpclient 4.3.3 how do I accept only one specific self signed certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm building a rest client which should only accept responses with one specific certificate. I tried to use a response Interceptor to compare a hash to identify and check that the right certificate is used. But I don't know how to get the server certificate from the response. The methods I found are all deprecated in httpclient 4.3.3.

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().addInterceptorLast(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {

  @Override
  public void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException
  {
    //how do I get the certificate here?
    String sha1Hex = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(cert.getEncoded());

    boolean check = sha1Hex.equals("xxxxxxxx");
  }

}).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how thus can be done

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().addInterceptorLast(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {

    @Override
    public void process(
            HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        HttpCoreContext coreContext = HttpCoreContext.adapt(context);
        ManagedHttpClientConnection conn = coreContext.getConnection(ManagedHttpClientConnection.class);
        SSLSession sslSession = conn.getSSLSession();
        if (sslSession != null) {
            X509Certificate[] certs = sslSession.getPeerCertificateChain();
            if (certs.length == 1) {
                String sha1Hex = null;
                try {
                    sha1Hex = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(certs[0].getEncoded());
                } catch (CertificateEncodingException ex) {
                    throw new HttpException("Messged up cert", ex);
                }
                boolean check = sha1Hex.equals("xxxxxxxx");
            }
        }
    }

}).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

However, a better way to accomplish the same, which I would recommend, is to initialize the client's SSL context with trust material consisting of the certificate you want your client to trust.